# Elpy Dependecies in Virtual Env

Tags: python, elpy

Elpy is dependent on a few python packages like `jedi`, `yapf`, etc.  However when I create enter a new virtual env and enter it using `pyvenv-activate` elpy is unable to find those packages without me installing them in the virtual environment.

I'd rather not install them in the virtual because it's a pain to do every time and those packages aren't really a requirement for others working on the project, just for me because I'm using elpy.

Is there anyway to point elpy to the global installs for these packages?

Comment: Very good point. There is an [open discussion](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1022) on Elpy about that (you can +1 it :) ). It is possible for emacs packages to manage the python dependencies differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install jedi/yapf packages in a separate virtualenv and just add `$VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python*/site-packages/` to your `PYTHONPATH` or to your virtualenv using `add2virtualenv`. Make sure you are using the same Python version for both virtualenvs.

Alternatively, you can install Elpy and the other packages globally (or user-local) and use the `--system-site-packages` argument to virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper's `toggleglobalsitepackages` to give your virtualenv access to those packages.

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/629) and you can submit a patch to make it better.